# Prove that if $a_1,...a_n $ all converge to a, then the following also converges to a:

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I already got the solution of this exercise, but I used another proof than the one in the solution (which is a bit longer than mine), and I would like to know if this is a valid proof.

> Prove that if $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ converge to $a$, then the following also converges to $a$: $$s_n=\frac{a_1+...a_n}{n}$$

If $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ converge to $a$, we can rewrite $s_n$ as:

$$s_n=\frac{a+a+...+a}{n} = \frac{na}{n} = a$$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: No this isn't a valid proof. Why would you think $a_1$ converges to $a$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: I'm not sure you really want $a_i$ to be sequences.

Comment: Yeah I made some mistakes Sorry

Comment: @Poujh No problem, any idea on how to correct them?

Comment: You must first be clear whether $s_j$ and $a_j$ are sequences or just elements of some sequence. This makes some difference, but no matter what your proof is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since you don't know that $a_j=a$ you can't just claim that $s_n={na\over n}$. Take for example $a_j$ are all the sequences $1/n$, consequently $a=0$, but certainly $s_2 = {a_1+a_2\over 2}$ isn't $0$, it's actually the sequence $1/n$ too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're having trouble with the concept/intuition for a sequence.

A sequence is just a list of points/numbers.  And we want to know one question: as you read that list from top to bottom, the further and further along you get on the list, are the values approaching something?

Let's look at an example.  Let's take the sequence: $1$, $1.9$, $1.99$, $1.999$, $1.9999$, etc.  Here, the first term in the sequence is $a_{1} = 1$.  The second term is $a_{2} = 1.9$.  As you read this list from top to bottom, do you notice anything about the behavior of the items in the list?  Are they getting closer and closer to one particular value as you get further and further down the list?  Yes!  They are getting closer to $1.9999...$ with the $9$'s repeating, and this is just another way to write the number $2$.  Because of this, we would say the sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $2$.  We don't really talk about a single point in the sequence converging to $2$.  For example, $a_{1}$, which is $1$ in this example, doesn't converge to $2$.  It's just one point.  "Converging" means you look further and further down the list, and ask: are the values getting closer and closer to a number?  So, you can say an entire sequence converges, like $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, but you can't really say a point like $a_{1}$ converges.  Unfortunately, mathematicians sometimes abuse notation and say "the sequence $a_{n}$ converges".  In this sentence, we really mean to write "the sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges, but laziness makes us omit the curly brackets, so it makes it look like we are talking about a single point, but we aren't.  We mean the sequence as a whole.

Here is an example of a sequence that doesn't converge.  Take $1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, ...$.  Here, $a_{1} = 1$, $a_{2} = -1$, $a_{3} = 1$, $a_{4} = -1$, etc.  As you keep reading further and further down the list, are the values getting close to a single number?  Nope!  They keep alternating between -1 and 1.  Back and forth.  Since they aren't getting closer to a single number as you go further and further down the list, this sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ doesn't converge.

Now, the reason your proof is wrong is because you are saying the term $a_{1}$ converges to $a$, and the single term $a_{2}$ converges to $a$, etc.  But by the above discussion, that's now how sequences work.  $a_{1}$ remains $a_{1}$ -- it doesn't change.  But as $n$ gets bigger and bigger (i.e., as you keep reading further and further down the list in the sequence), the $a_{n}$'s are getting close and closer to $a$.  But your proof as it is doesn't work.  $a_{1}$ doesn't converge to $a$.  It just stays as $a_{1}$.